# Animation callback altering a different variable

Tags: ios, swift, animation, closures

I have a button which shows a view and which automatically goes away after specified time interval. Now if the button is pressed again while the view is already visible then it should go away and show a new view and the timer for new view be reset.

On the button press I have following code:

```
func showToast() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil

    removeToast()

    var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var toAddView = appDelegate.window!

    toastView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, toAddView.frame.height, toAddView.frame.width, 48))
    toastView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    toAddView.addSubview(toastView)

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("removeToast"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.toastView.frame.origin.y -= 48
    })
}
```

To remove toast i have the following code:

```
func removeToast() {
    if toastView != nil {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
            animations: { () -> Void in
                self.toastView.frame.origin.y += 48
            },
            completion: {(completed: Bool) -> Void in
                self.toastView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.toastView = nil
            })
    }
}
```

Now even though I reset the timer each time by doing `timer.invalidate()` I get two calls in `removeToast()` which removes the newly inserted view. Can it be that `UIView.animate` be causing problems, I'm not getting how to debug the two callbacks for `removeToast()`. A demo project showing the behavior is [here](https://www.github.com/shahankit/TimerTest)

**NOTE:** I did find some post saying to use `dispatch_after()` instead of timer, also as asked by @jervine10, but it does not suffice my scenario. As if I use `dispatch_after` then it's difficult to invalidate GCD call. Is there something that could be accomplished with NSTimers. I think that NSTimers are meant for this and there's something that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just for what it's worth, I'm getting the same thing whereby the timer won't invalidate, and even setting it to nil, it calls itself again.

Comment: @AndyDunn I had a workaround with the issue by removing the completion block of removing the toastView. Now I keep the toastView and only hide it instead of removing from superView, but still getting two timer calls.

Comment: In the end I just added a flag to check if the timer should be stopped. Far from ideal but it works reliably.

Comment: In case you still want to solve this, please consider posting the whole class, since you are passing `self` to the timer, there might be more than one instance created.

Comment: @Mazyod entire demo project is there in link: https://github.com/shahankit/TimerTest

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the repo, I should've seen it. Since your issue isn't related to `NSTimer`, I'll change the wording a bit on the question to better illustrate the problem to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not seeing your sample project, and thanks for directing me towards it. I can clearly see where the issue is, and the solution is super simple. Change remove toast to this:

```
func removeToast() {

    guard let toastView = self.toastView else {
        return
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1,
        animations: { () -> Void in
            toastView.frame.origin.y += 48
        },
        completion: {(completed: Bool) -> Void in
            toastView.removeFromSuperview()

            if self.toastView == toastView {
                self.toastView = nil
            }
        })
}
```

Basically, the problem is that you are capturing `self` in the animation blocks, not `toastView`. So, once the animation blocks execute asynchronously, they will remove the *new* `toastView` set in the previous function.

The solution is simple and also fixes possible race conditions, and that is to capture the toastView in a variable. Finally, we check if the instance variable is equal to the view we are removing, we nullify it.

**Tip**: Consider using `weak` reference for `toastView`

Answer (score 0):

Use `dispatch_after` to call a method after a set period of time instead of a timer. It would look like this:

```
let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC))
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
   self.removeToast()
}
```

Comment: and How do I invalidate the dispatch function from being called?

Comment: You wouldn't. Why do you need it invalidated?

Comment: Just look at the function removeToast I don't want it to be called again. If it gets called then it will remove the toastView and that is what is happening currently.